# Problems saving file in PHP ("failed to open stream: No such file or directory")

Tags: php, html, file-upload, ftp, save

I am simply trying to save a file containing the serialized values of a form.

### The Simple Form

```
    <h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
    <form form method="post"> 
       First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="
       
      <?PHP 
      
      echo ($_POST['fname']) 
      
      ?>">
       
<br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="Save" value="Save Current Form"> 
   Save File Name As: <input type="text" name="saveFile">
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="Load" value="Load Old Form">      
       Load File: <input type="text" name="loadFile">

    </form>
```

### When i save/load the file i use the PHP code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['Save'])) {

$PostArray = $_POST;
$s = base64_encode(serialize($PostArray)); 
$file = sprintf('/SavedForms/%s',$_POST['saveFile']);
file_put_contents($file, $s);

}

if (isset($_POST['Load'])) {

$file = sprintf("/SavedForms/%s",$_POST['loadFile']);
$_POST = unserialize(base64_decode(file_get_contents($file)));

}
?>
```

But it simply tells me

> (when i try the save the file name "aaa")

that: "**Warning:** file_put_contents(/SavedForms/aaa) [[function.file-put-contents]](http://pansycheung.com/Jul17/function.file-put-contents): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in"

I already have created the directory `/SavedForms/` in the file as seen in the image below...

[image]

Could someone please let me know what i am doing wrong here!?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the leading forward slash from the directory:

```
$file = sprintf('SavedForms/%s',$_POST['saveFile']);
```

Assuming that `SavedForms` is in the same directory as the executing php script.

Paths are relative to the script. By putting a leading slash, you are declaring an absolute path from the very root directory of your machine. This means it is currently looking for `SavedForms` in the root directory, and of course, it fails to find it

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your project.